# Sql - Calculate Inventory Days

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I'm trying to calculate inventory day's over time. I have an issue getting the actual amount of day's in inventory for the last month. So as for the first row, the 9 days is correct. However the second row should show 34. Since I want to calculate the days between Inv_date and "today's" Date. Let's presume when I'm writing this, today's date is '2021-03-25'.

So I have a table such as:

| Transdate | Inv_Date | Purch_Date | InvDays |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 20210219 | Null | 9 |
| 2021-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 20210219 | Null | 40 |

What I'm expecting is:

| Transdate | Inv_Date | Purch_Date | InvDays |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 20210219 | Null | 9 |
| 2021-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 20210219 | Null | 34 |

My Sql-script for the InvdDays calculation is:

```
case when left(Getdate(),8) >= left(convert(varchar,Transdate,112),8) then 
datediff(day,Inv_date,
dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,1,Transdate))
)
else 
isnull(ABS(DATEDIFF(day, Inv_date, isnull(Purch_Date, Getdate()))),0) end as InvDaysStandQty
```

Comment: Please explain the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I speculate that you want the number of days from the last day of `transdate` and `inv_date`.  That would be something like this:

```
select datediff(day, inv_date,
                (case when convert(date, getdate()) < eomonth(transdate)
                      then getdate() else eomonth(transdate)
                 end)
                )
```

There might be an off-by-1 error, because you haven't actually explained the logic.

Comment: I've updated my question,  So as for the first row, the 9 days is correct. However the second row should show 34. Since I want to calculate the days between Inv_date and "today's" Date. Since Purchase date will always be null.

Comment: @user3052850 . . . Purchase date is not used in this logic.  I think this does what you want.